# Postgres: Update table sorting on new record inserted or removed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to sort table automatically by specified row each time a new record is added (or removed or updated).

For that, I've create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION pid_cluster_function() 
   RETURNS TRIGGER 
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
   -- trigger logic
     
     cluster verbose public.pid using pid_idx;
END;
$$
```

and add a trigger

```
CREATE trigger pid_cluster_trigger 
    after INSERT or update or DELETE on public.pid  
    FOR EACH row  
    execute procedure pid_cluster_function();
```

but with adding a record

```
INSERT INTO public.pid (pid,pid_name) VALUES ('111','new 111');
```

I've received such an error

```
SQL Error [55006]: ERROR: cannot CLUSTER "pid" because it is being used by active queries in this session
  Where: SQL statement "cluster verbose public.pid using pid_idx"
PL/pgSQL function pid_cluster_function() line 5 at SQL statement
```

What is the reason for this error?
Or is it possible to achieve sorting by adding or modifying the records in some other way?

Comment: Records are not sorted when they are in the database, But the SQL statement that is getting them out of the database will sort them (when it does have an `ORDER BY ...` clause )

Comment: Why would you even try to sort? Any select statement with a different order by would get a different result anyway

Comment: The idea is to speed up the fetching of the data and try to avoid codebase changes

Comment: If you have a codebase that relies on some implicit sort order (_without_ using order by), then your codebase is already broken and it's better to fix that bug, rather than messing around with triggers.

Comment: So you want to speed things up by using a process that slows things down. From [CLUSTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html): *When an index scan is used, a temporary copy of the table is created that contains the table data in the index order. Temporary copies of each index on the table are created as well. Therefore, you need free space on disk at least equal to the sum of the table size and the index sizes.*  and *When a sequential scan and sort is used, a temporary sort file is also created...*. All that disk activity will be detrimental to performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you, everyone, in the comments. I see that my idea is not clever =)